# Opening an XML File

Tags: android, xml

I received an XML file for android development and I am attempting to open it. The problem is when I open it in eclipse or notepad it comes up with gibberish and special characters. Is there any way to read it in its original readable code?

Comment: Can you post a link to the XML file? That would be most useful.

Comment: try opening with an web browser

Comment: Sure, I uploaded it to google drive. Here is the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6YEQds6FJUIU01mWk1GTEpTbU0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried opening it with a web browser but it did not work. It only said "This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

Comment: Specify the origin of the file. (server, operating system) maybe it has a few characters native to Linux that don't play well with Windows.

Comment: I believe it came from an APK file.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever that file is, it definitely isn't an XML file. Ask whoever gave it to you whether they gave you the right file, whether it's really supposed to be or contain XML, what they used to produce it...